# Window 7 Crash BSOD? Please tell me what's wrong?

Tags: windows-7, 64-bit, bsod

My system is crashing, but after I unistall utorrent, it works fine. Have a look at Crash Dump.

http://dl.dropbox.com/u/32657135/Minidump.rar

I'm using Windows 7 64-bit.

Here is information from the first crash:

```
SYSTEM_THREAD_EXCEPTION_NOT_HANDLED_M (1000007e)

Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
fffff880`033d55e8 fffff800`03180ef4 nt!memmove+0x1d1
fffff880`033d55f0 fffff800`03194a2f nt!EtwpLogKernelEvent+0x2a4
fffff880`033d5690 fffff880`011e9692 nt!EtwpTraceFileName+0x15f
fffff880`033d5720 fffff880`011ea43b fileinfo!FIStreamLog+0x1be
fffff880`033d57f0 fffff880`011e7563 fileinfo!FIEnumerate+0x117
fffff880`033d5870 fffff880`011e760b fileinfo!FIControlDispatchSystemControl+0x73
fffff880`033d58b0 fffff800`03332968 fileinfo!FIControlDispatch+0x4b
fffff880`033d58f0 fffff800`03465936 nt!WmipForwardWmiIrp+0x16c
fffff880`033d5970 fffff800`0346645b nt!WmipSendWmiIrpToTraceDeviceList+0xe6
fffff880`033d59d0 fffff800`03476e44 nt!WmiTraceRundownNotify+0x6b
fffff880`033d5a20 fffff800`034e2a7c nt!EtwpKernelTraceRundown+0xc4
fffff880`033d5a50 fffff800`034e2b7f nt!EtwpUpdateLoggerGroupMasks+0x22c
fffff880`033d5b50 fffff800`032f1859 nt!EtwpStopLoggerInstance+0x4f
fffff880`033d5b90 fffff800`032f15d0 nt!EtwpStopTrace+0x129
fffff880`033d5c00 fffff800`03509f45 nt! ?? ::NNGAKEGL::`string'+0x58e5c
fffff880`033d5c70 fffff800`030a5471 nt!PerfDiagpProxyWorker+0x1c5
fffff880`033d5cb0 fffff800`03335f7a nt!ExpWorkerThread+0x111
fffff880`033d5d40 fffff800`0308c9c6 nt!PspSystemThreadStartup+0x5a
fffff880`033d5d80 00000000`00000000 nt!KiStartSystemThread+0x16
```

Here is information from the second crash:

```
NTFS_FILE_SYSTEM (24)

Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
fffff880`036de1e8 fffff880`01437a88 nt!KeBugCheckEx
fffff880`036de1f0 fffff880`01526363 Ntfs! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+0x2b49
fffff880`036de230 fffff800`024f6fec Ntfs! ?? ::NNGAKEGL::`string'+0x830e
fffff880`036de260 fffff800`024f6a6d nt!_C_specific_handler+0x8c
fffff880`036de2d0 fffff800`024f5845 nt!RtlpExecuteHandlerForException+0xd
fffff880`036de300 fffff800`025067c1 nt!RtlDispatchException+0x415
fffff880`036de9e0 fffff800`024cb3c2 nt!KiDispatchException+0x135
fffff880`036df080 fffff800`024c9cca nt!KiExceptionDispatch+0xc2
fffff880`036df260 fffff800`02478eb9 nt!KiGeneralProtectionFault+0x10a
fffff880`036df3f8 fffff800`0249b52d nt!RealSuccessor+0x39
fffff880`036df400 fffff880`014ad652 nt!RtlEnumerateGenericTableWithoutSplayingAvl+0x1d
fffff880`036df430 fffff880`014b5fad Ntfs!NtfsFlushVolume+0x436
fffff880`036df560 fffff880`014b66b4 Ntfs!NtfsCommonFlushBuffers+0x459
fffff880`036df640 fffff880`00c02bcf Ntfs!NtfsFsdFlushBuffers+0x104
fffff880`036df6b0 fffff880`00c016df fltmgr!FltpLegacyProcessingAfterPreCallbacksCompleted+0x24f
*** WARNING: Unable to verify timestamp for AsDsm.sys
*** ERROR: Module load completed but symbols could not be loaded for AsDsm.sys
fffff880`036df740 fffff880`0123035a fltmgr!FltpDispatch+0xcf
fffff880`036df7a0 00000000`00000002 AsDsm+0x135a
fffff880`036df7a8 fffff880`036dfb10 0x2
fffff880`036df7b0 00000000`00000000 0xfffff880`036dfb10
```

Here is information from the second crash, when looking in the exception record:

```
Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
fffff880`036df3f8 fffff800`0249b52d nt!RealSuccessor+0x39
fffff880`036df400 fffff880`014ad652 nt!RtlEnumerateGenericTableWithoutSplayingAvl+0x1d
fffff880`036df430 fffff880`014b5fad Ntfs!NtfsFlushVolume+0x436
fffff880`036df560 fffff880`014b66b4 Ntfs!NtfsCommonFlushBuffers+0x459
fffff880`036df640 fffff880`00c02bcf Ntfs!NtfsFsdFlushBuffers+0x104
fffff880`036df6b0 fffff880`00c016df fltmgr!FltpLegacyProcessingAfterPreCallbacksCompleted+0x24f
fffff880`036df740 fffff880`0123035a fltmgr!FltpDispatch+0xcf
fffff880`036df7a0 00000000`00000002 AsDsm+0x135a
fffff880`036df7a8 fffff880`036dfb10 0x2
fffff880`036df7b0 00000000`00000000 0xfffff880`036dfb10
```

The third crash is similar to the second crash.

The fourth crash is also similar, but doesn't mention AsDsm:

```
Child-SP          RetAddr           Call Site
fffff880`039d8798 fffff880`0145fa88 nt!KeBugCheckEx
fffff880`039d87a0 fffff880`01463df3 Ntfs! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+0x2b49
fffff880`039d87e0 fffff800`024b2fec Ntfs! ?? ::FNODOBFM::`string'+0xff8
fffff880`039d8810 fffff800`024b2a6d nt!_C_specific_handler+0x8c
fffff880`039d8880 fffff800`024b1845 nt!RtlpExecuteHandlerForException+0xd
fffff880`039d88b0 fffff800`024c27c1 nt!RtlDispatchException+0x415
fffff880`039d8f90 fffff800`024873c2 nt!KiDispatchException+0x135
fffff880`039d9630 fffff800`02485cca nt!KiExceptionDispatch+0xc2
fffff880`039d9810 fffff880`01468815 nt!KiGeneralProtectionFault+0x10a
fffff880`039d99a0 fffff880`01503777 Ntfs!NtfsAcquireFcbWithPaging+0x95
fffff880`039d9a00 fffff880`01501fd2 Ntfs!NtfsFindPrefixHashEntry+0x44e
fffff880`039d9b30 fffff880`014ff911 Ntfs!NtfsFindStartingNode+0x452
fffff880`039d9c00 fffff880`01468a3d Ntfs!NtfsCommonCreate+0x3e1
fffff880`039d9de0 fffff800`02493a88 Ntfs!NtfsCommonCreateCallout+0x1d
fffff880`039d9e10 fffff880`014691bf nt!KeExpandKernelStackAndCalloutEx+0xd8
fffff880`039d9ef0 fffff880`0150299c Ntfs!NtfsCommonCreateOnNewStack+0x4f
fffff880`039d9f50 00000000`00000000 Ntfs!NtfsFsdCreate+0x1ac
```

Comment: Have you tried to reinstall after uninstall utorrent?

Comment: Stop using utorrent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that two of the crashes mention `AsDsm` after running them through WinDBG (or OSR Online).

Here is more information on the file:

```
Asdsm.sys
Data Security Manager Driver
Driver File
Windows (R) Codename Longhorn DDK
Digitally signed: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. (VeriSign Time Stamping - G2)
```

Searching for `Data Security Manager`, I find that it is `Asus Data Security Management`.

It seems that this is protecting the data being accessed in one or another way, try to see if you can exclude the offending program from being denied access. If not, you could consider removing the security program / driver but then you don't have the added security benefit anymore. Although this is specific to Asus, and a lot of people on the world don't run this...

So, to summarize:

1. `Asus Data Security Management` makes your PC crash because data can't be accessed.
2. You can alleviate this situation by either excluding the offending program or uninstalling  AsDsm.

Comment: There's also a chance that the drive or filesystem is bad. I'd recommend a `chkdsk` in addition to the above.

Comment: @EKW: Affirmative, a bad sector or something corrupt could result in the above. That, alongside checking S.M.A.R.T. information could result in a much better conclusion...

Comment: Thanks it worked!!, Can i fix my disk without re installing windows 7. Please tell me which tool does it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user1043815: The tool I mentioned above should do that? If you removed it, it should be gone? You can try running `chkdsk` and `sfc /scannow` in an attempt to get rid of corruption.